# Permissão negada Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, apache

Estou tentando criar meu primeiro projeto laravel com vuejs. Instalei o apache no ubuntu 16.04 e naveguei até a pasta /var/www/html. lá rodei o seguinte comando:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel --prefer-dist
```

mas quando rodo esse comando ele me da o seguinte erro:

```
[ErrorException]  mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Procurando pela internet todo mundo diz para dar permissão 777 para html, mas isso não é uma solução viável, já que se fosse em produção, isso tornaria o servidor inseguro. Outros disseram pra rodar como sudo, mas o próprio instalador desaconcelha isso. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Você pode instalar o Laravel em qualquer pasta não precisa ser exatamente essa, dê a permissão de escrita e como é desenvolvimento não tem problema, quando for colocar em um servidor de hospedagem já está configurado para receber as página isso não precisa ser preocupação sua ...

Comment: então nesse caso, posso criar uma pasta ali dentro e dar permissão 777? Mas na hr de colocar em produção, como é feito o processo?

Comment: Então como é desenvolvimento pode criar sim uma pasta ali dentro ou em qualquer pasta que tenha permissão, insclusive o Laravel executa o servidor embutido no PHP nos testes. Na parte de hospedagem a própria contratada faz as configurações especificas liberando a você as necessárias para alguma configuração particular, agora vai depender também muito de qual hospedagem você contratou, cada uma é de uma maneira. No seu caso se está se preocupando muito além não vejo necessidade.

Comment: é que eu penso em criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento mais semelhante possível do de produção, mas nesse caso, mais pra frente eu vejo como fazer. :)

Comment: Então se tem que ver a parte de servidor apache e permissões, estudar isso então...